# Lists questions and community wiki's

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if a specific question which basically asks for a list of references that would sufficiently cover a topic would be considered on topic for the site or if it would be closed as subjective. I was thinking specifically that the question could be made a community wiki; I've seen questions that are similar in spirit asked on mathoverflow where they are almost always made into community wikis (as opposed to being closed). The specific question I'm asking about is the subject of the intensional content of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, examples of papers on this topic are Feferman's [Arithmetization of Metamathematics in a General Setting](https://philpapers.org/rec/FEFAOM) and Auerbach's [Intensionality and the Gödel Theorems](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4319795)

The question would be something like:

> What literature has been written on the topic of the intentionality of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, and the philosophical problems with understanding whether or not the formal sentence abbreviated as "Con(PA)" *actually* expresses the consistency of PA? What would a sufficient list covering the main pieces of literature on this topic be?

I am open to refinements of the question if that is too subjective of a reference request.

Comment: I am not too acquainted with the philosophical and mathematical details and discourses around Gödel, but on first sight, I would ask two separate reference requests: First about Gödel's intentionality itself (which probably will focus on sources which discuss letters, manuscripts, etc or include answers quoting them directly), second about the interpretations of the formal proposition (which may coincide, but can also include material/formal considerations of coherency and consequences different from Gödel's own account). Sufficiency should be omitted altogether, this is subjective.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Given any philosophical topic, there is only a finite amount of literature written on it. Given that, there are only a finite amount of positions that exist in the literature on that topic. Call a sample of literature about a certain topic *sufficient* if it contains at least one paper representative of each view expressed in the literature. Is that a subjective definition, because it feels objective to me.